# Season 5: Why does Nurse Jackie keep calling Charlie?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, nurse-jackie

In Season 5, why does Nurse Jackie keep calling Charlie?

> Charlie died of a drug overdose in the final episode of Season 4, so this doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to figure out the same thing.  Maybe it is a sort of "therapy" for her.  The only explanation is that his father didn't close Charlie's phone account; therefore, she is still able to call Charlie.  Charlie definitely died last season.

Comment: Also, in a later episode in Season 5, you can see Charlie's father listening to Jackie's voice mail messages. This leads to Charlie's father and Jackie having sex.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [press release for the second episode of season five](http://www.spoilertv.com/2013/03/nurse-jackie-episodes-501-510-press.html), “Luck of the Drawing”:

> Jackie, overwhelmed by the day, downloads to **the only person who will
>   understand. She calls Charlie Cruz’s voicemail**.

There is also a pay-off later in the season, in the [fifth episode](http://www.spoilertv.com/2013/03/nurse-jackie-episodes-501-510-press.html), "Good Thing":

> Later that night, Jackie and Frank skip the fancy restaurant in favor
>   of a pub. It’s a great date with a good guy. All is going well until
>   Jackie’s phone rings: It’s Mike Cruz, urging her to lose the date. She
>   follows Cruz to his apartment and **he confronts her about calling
>   Charlie’s phone.** He falls apart talking about Charlie. A moment of
>   shared grief turns into connection and need and they have sex.

[This also links back to people understanding each other](http://www.nursetogether.com/missed-messages-have-consequences-nurse-jackie):

> Jackie meets Cruz in his apartment where there are photos of Charlie
>   all over the place. He tells Jackie he is having a hard time getting
>   over Charlie’s death. He also confesses to Jackie that he could not
>   get rid of his son’s cell phone and has heard all of the messages that
>   Jackie has made over the past few months. **He shares with Jackie that
>   she is the only one who understands and he needs her help.**

Answer (score 0):

Because Jackie is not ready and able to deal with AA and having a real sponsor, so instead she calls the now deceased Charlie. It's her form of therapeutic release.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's to hear his voice on the answering machine